# Calculate perplexity of word2vec model

Tags: python, nlp, gensim, word2vec, language-model

I trained Gensim W2V model on 500K sentences (around 60K) words and I want to calculate the perplexity.

1. What will be the best way to do so?
2. for 60K words, how can I check what will be a proper amount of data?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

If you want to calculate the perplexity, you have first to retrieve the loss. 
On the `gensim.models.word2vec.Word2Vec` constructor, pass the `compute_loss=True` parameter - this way, `gensim` will store the loss for you while training.
Once trained, you can call the [`get_latest_training_loss()`](https://radimrehurek.com/gensim/models/word2vec.html#gensim.models.word2vec.Word2Vec.get_latest_training_loss) method to retrieve the loss.

Since the loss in the cross-entropy loss of the skip-gram model, 2 to the power of the loss will give you the preplexity. (2**loss)

Comment: I get loss of 36672808.0 does it make sense?

Comment: Did you run any training? Tell me what is the perplexity and the number of total words in your vocabulary, it will be easier to determine if it makes sense