# How can I test a word2vec over development data?

Tags: python, neural-network, nlp, word2vec, perplexity

In a computer assignment, it's requested to implement word2vec algorithm to generate dense vectors for some words using a neural network. I implemented the neural network and trained it over training data. First, how can I test it over the test data? The question asks to draw a plot showing the perplexity for the training and test data during training (epochs). I can do that for the loss, which is something like this:

```
EPOCH: 0 LOSS: 27030.09155006593
EPOCH: 0 P_LOSS: 24637.964948774144
EPOCH: 0 PP: inf
/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/ipykernel_launcher.py:121: RuntimeWarning: overflow encountered in double_scalars
EPOCH: 1 LOSS: 25349.086587261085
EPOCH: 1 P_LOSS: 22956.95998596929
EPOCH: 1 PP: inf
EPOCH: 2 LOSS: 24245.455581381622
EPOCH: 2 P_LOSS: 21853.32898008983
EPOCH: 2 PP: inf
EPOCH: 3 LOSS: 23312.976009712416
EPOCH: 3 P_LOSS: 20920.849408420647
```

Which I gained by the following code:

```
    # CYCLE THROUGH EACH EPOCH
    for i in range(0, self.epochs):

        self.loss = 0
        self.loss_prob = 0
        # CYCLE THROUGH EACH TRAINING SAMPLE
        for w_t, w_c in training_data:

            # FORWARD PASS
            y_pred, h, u = self.forward_pass(w_t)

            # CALCULATE ERROR
            EI = np.sum([np.subtract(y_pred, word) for word in w_c], axis=0)

            # BACKPROPAGATION
            self.backprop(EI, h, w_t)

            # CALCULATE LOSS
            self.loss += -np.sum([u[word.index(1)] for word in w_c]) + len(w_c) * np.log(np.sum(np.exp(u)))
            self.loss_prob += -2*np.log(len(w_c)) -np.sum([u[word.index(1)] for word in w_c]) + (len(w_c) * np.log(np.sum(np.exp(u))))

        print('EPOCH:',i, 'LOSS:', self.loss)
        print('EPOCH:',i, 'P_LOSS:', self.loss_prob)
        print('EPOCH:',i, 'PP:', 2**self.loss_prob)
```

However, I don't know how to find the perplexity for the training and development data in each epoch. Based on [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53765598/calculate-perplexity-of-word2vec-model), it's said perplexity is `2**loss`. However, as I tried this formula, I gained `INF`. Could you guide me how can I calculate perplexity? Can I do it in the current code, or should I apply a function over whole development data?

Answer (score 0):

Indeed, `2**20000` overflows the float. You should normalize the loss per example, i.e., divide by your training data size. Back-propagation works even if you sum them because dividing by a constant does not change the derivative, but in this way, the loss is not invariant to data size.

Answer (score -1):

You can solve the INF problem using decimal.

```
import decimal
decimal.Decimal(2)**decimal.Decimal(loss)
```